# У меня есть тест на jquery.Мне надо чтобы после перезагрузке страницы с тестом все результаты в "radio" очистились

Tags: javascript

Вы перезагрузили страницу и вы должны выбирать правильный вариант еще раз

```js
function result(percent) {
  if (percent <= 10) return 'Ты не прошел тест!';
  if (percent <= 30) return 'Тебе надо еще поработать';
  if (percent <= 60) return 'Повтори тему еще раз!';
  if (percent <= 80) return 'Ну почти!';
   if (percent <= 100) return 'Красава, ты прошел тест!';
}

$(function() {

  $('.questionForm input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    var answer = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < $('.group').length; i++) {
      $('.group').eq(i).each(function(id, elem) {
        if ($(elem).find('input:checked').length != 0) {
          if ($(elem).find('input:checked').attr('value') == 1) {
            answer++;
          }
        }
      })
    }
    var percent = (answer / $('.group').length) * 100; 
    $("#wrap").hide();
 $("#mc-container").show();
 $(".share_title").show();
 $("#answers-container").show();
    $(".result").show("slow", function() {
    $(".result").replaceWith("<div class='replace-container'>" + "<div class='replace'>" + "Тест пройден на: " + "<p>" + percent + '%' + "</p>" + "</div>")
    $(".result1").replaceWith("<div class='replace1'>" + "<p>" + result(percent) + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>")
    });

    return false;
  })
})
```

```html
  
  

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <br>
    <font size="+2">
      <p align="center">
        <div class="questionBlock">
          <font size="+1">
            <br>

          <form method="POST" action="test.php" class="questionForm">
    <div class="group">
     <h3>JavaScript - это</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q1" value="0">Язык разметка<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q1" value="1">Язык программирования<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q1" value="0">Язык описания внешнего вида<br>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Чтобы добавить код JS надо написать</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript text="javascript"><br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript="text/javascript"><br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q2" value="1">&ltscript type="text/javascript"><br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q2" value="0">&ltscript type="javascript"><br> 
    </div> 
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Чтобы добавить комментарий надо</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q3" value="0">использовать */<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q3" value="0">использовать **<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q3" value="1">использовать //<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q3" value="1">использовать &lt!--<br>
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Как вывести слово "привет"</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q4" value="1">Через alert ('привет');<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q4" value="0">Через hi ('привет');<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q4" value="0">Через alert (привет);<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q4" value="0">Через alert  'привет';<br> 
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Какой из вариантов создаст переменную "a"</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q5" value="0">var = a;<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q5" value="1">var a;<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q5" value="0">$a;<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q5" value="0">var<br> 
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Какой вариант правильный</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q6" value="0"><div class="code"><pre style="background-color: #bfbfbf;color:#000"> <span style="color:#00f;font-weight:700">var</span> x;
 <span style="color:#3c4c72;font-weight:700">alert</span>(<span style="color:#0000cd">x</span>);</pre></div>
     <input type = "radio" name="q6" value="1"><div class="code"><pre style="background-color: #bfbfbf;color:#000"> <span style="color:#00f;font-weight:700">var</span> x = 10;
 <span style="color:#3c4c72;font-weight:700">alert</span>(<span style="color:#0000cd">x</span>);</pre></div><br>
    </div>   
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Какой вариант неправильный</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q7" value="0">var 2 = 2;<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q7" value="1">var _name = "Denis";<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q7" value="0">var _user = Vasea<br>
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Какой вариант неправильный</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q8" value="0">var gorod = "Moscow";<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q8" value="1">var city = "Moscow"<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q8" value="0">var cityMoscow = "Moscow"<br>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Какой оператор неравенства неправильный</h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q9" value="0">=!<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q9" value="0">==!<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q9" value="0">!==<br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q9" value="1">!=<br> 
    </div>  
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="group">
     <h3>Выберете опрератор "меньше или равно" </h3>
     <input type = "radio" name="q10" value="0">><br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q10" value="0">=><br>
     <input type = "radio" name="q10" value="0">>=<br>
    </div>

              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Посмотреть результаты" name="submit">
              <br>
              <br>
            </form>
          </font>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <span>Тест пройден на <p>0%</p></span>
  </div>
  <div class="result1">
    <p>Вы не прошли тест!</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, чтоб галочек не было?

Comment: `<form autocomlete="off">`

Comment: да, я имею в виду чтобы не было галочек

Comment: Тег `font`? это шутка или что?

Answer (score 0):

Можно при загрузке страницы использовать следующий код

```
$("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```